# "DuplicateResourceName" creating azurerm_network_security_group dynamic rules

Tags: azure, terraform

As a terraform user I'm interested on allowing ICMP&TCP protocols between 2 virtual machines. In order to achieve that I created adynamic network_security_group but terraform is throwing below error:

```
│ Error: creating/updating Network Security Group: (Name "***01-tf-SG***" / Resource Group "RG_Terraform"): network.SecurityGroupsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidRequestFormat" Message="Cannot parse the request." Details=[{"code":"DuplicateResourceName","message":"Resource /subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/ has two child resources with the same name (01-tf-SG)."}]
│
│   with azurerm_network_security_group.linux_vm_nsg,
│   on main.tf line 291, in resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "linux_vm_nsg":
│  291: resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "linux_vm_nsg" {
│
╵
```

It seems the problem is related the name 01-tf-SG but name field is mandatory and even using different names for resouce_name and content_name the issue still happens.

See the Terraform code from mian.tf file:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "linux_vm_nsg" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.main]
  name                = "01-tf-SG"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = toset(["Icmp", "Tcp"])
    content {
      name                       = "01-tf-SG"
      priority                   = 100
      direction                  = "Inbound"
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = security_rule.value
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "*"
      source_address_prefix      = "172.16.25.10/32"
      destination_address_prefix = "10.0.1.10/32"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest doing something like `name = "01-tf-SG-${each.key}"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate different name for the `security_rule`. For example as follows:

```
  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = {for idx, val in ["Icmp", "Tcp"]: idx => val}
    content {
      name                       = "01-tf-SG-${each.security_rule.key}"
      priority                   = 100
      direction                  = "Inbound"
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = security_rule.value
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "*"
      source_address_prefix      = "172.16.25.10/32"
      destination_address_prefix = "10.0.1.10/32"
    }
  }
```